# How do I replace "new line" characters inside double quotes in php?

Tags: php, regex, csv

Ok, I have a csv file like this:

```
14 ; 1234,56 ; 10203 ; "ABC" ; "DFG" ; "Lorem \n ipsum \n dolor sit" \n
15 ; 234,16 ; 10204 ; "ABC" ; "DFG" ; "Lorem \n ipsum \n dolor sit" \n
16 ; 1234,15 ; 10304 ; "CCC" ; "DFG" ; "Lorem ipsum/dolor \n sit amet\consec" \n
```

and so on...

The file has almost 550000 lines.
How do I replace all \n characters inside double quotes at once?

I'm using PHP 5. Could it be done by preg_replace()?

Comment: Is there any \" inside any of these double quotes?

Comment: Yes, I have slashes inside quotes in some records.

Comment: I like RegEx, but in this case it is not safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you're using [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), but you can configure it to recognize individual fields including quoted information.

This way you can read your lines in one at a time and strip the new line characters at the field level rather than having to do an expensive RegEx operation on a large file all at once.

Slightly modified php code example from the documentation (replaced delimiter with ';'):

```
$row = 1;
$handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

data.txt

```
14 ; 1234,56 ; 10203 ; "ABC" ; "DFG" ; "text 
 text 
 more text"
15 ; 234,16 ; 10204 ; "ABC" ; "DFG" ; "text 
 text 
 more text"
```

This will be recognized as 2 lines instead of 6 because [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) will recognize the new line characters in the quotes as part of the field and not additional lines of data.

Comment: fgetcsv() Works perfectly, thanks you all guys! I'm new to PHP, and didn't knew this function.

Anyway, I'd like to see the regex pattern ...

Comment: Glad to be of service, I've only been exposed to fgetcsv() recently myself - can't help you on the RegEx side of things, I can use them but I'm not sure how to make it work for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

So do you actually have the string `'\n'` (not a new line character) on some lines? If so, you just need to escape the new line character:

```
str_replace("\\n", "*foo*", $csv)

// this will make the following change:
14 ; 1234,56 ; 10203 ; "ABC" ; "DFG" ; "text \n text \n more text" \n
// that to this:
14 ; 1234,56 ; 10203 ; "ABC" ; "DFG" ; "text *foo* text *foo* more text" \n
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function specific to read CSV files: `fgetcsv();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too well versed in extremely complex regex's, so assuming you're looking for a one time conversion I would write a quick script to open the csv in php, read the file (fgetcsv built into php5) and write (fputcsv) line by line into a new file while str_replace'ing the newline characters.

(If I wasn't looking for the monster regex on stackoverflow, that is.)